# my openbox config file (lubuntu-rc.xml) - the windows resizing keyboard shortcuts stopped working?

Tags: lubuntu, openbox

so this is really strange. Two days ago I installed lubuntu 17.10 on a new machine. I used my trusty lubuntu-rc.xml file and all my keyboard shortcuts worked fine. I have used this .config-file for the last three years on at least seven different machines,  and on all the versions of Lubuntu since then. I haven't made a change to the .config-files for at least a year.

I then erasted lubuntu 17.04 and installed 17.10 on another machine today. But now, only some of the keyboard shortcuts are working...

The common denominator for the non-working ones seems to be that they resize windows, or change windows from one desktop to another. 
W
hich is very annoying, since they are the most essential ones! It feels like I'm missing an arm without them... I'm bleeding to death here, please help?

I have the two machines right next to each other in this very moment. Both of them fully updated 17.10, but on different hardware. But two hours ago, the one was running 17.04 with the config file just fine, and the other was running 17.10 with the config file just fine. Now the one updated from 17.04 to 17.10 can't utilize all of the .config file. Both them are on a completely fresh install. I really don't get it.

Thank you for your time,

EDIT: 
here is the config file. it's kind of long. Most of my shortcuts that doesn't work are under the comment "EMILS SHORTCUTS".
Stackexhange doesn't allow the full file because of the characterlimit, so I have included about 2/3 of it below. 
[The whole file can be found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qxxwophdg1su8nk/lubuntu-rc.xml?dl=0)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openbox_config xmlns="http://openbox.org/3.4/rc">
  <resistance>
    <strength>10</strength>
    <screen_edge_strength>20</screen_edge_strength>
  </resistance>
  <focus>
    <focusNew>yes</focusNew>
    <!-- always try to focus new windows when they appear. other rules do
       apply -->
    <focusLast>yes</focusLast>
    <!-- focus the last used window when changing desktops, instead of the one
       under the mouse pointer. when followMouse is enabled -->
    <followMouse>no</followMouse>
    <!-- move focus to a window when you move the mouse into it -->
    <focusDelay>200</focusDelay>
    <!-- when followMouse is enabled, the mouse must be inside the window for
       this many milliseconds (1000 = 1 sec) before moving focus to it -->
    <raiseOnFocus>no</raiseOnFocus>
    <!-- when followMouse is enabled, and a window is given focus by moving the
       mouse into it, also raise the window -->
    <underMouse>no</underMouse>
  </focus>
  <placement>
    <policy>UnderMouse</policy>
    <!-- 'Smart' or 'UnderMouse' -->
    <center>yes</center>
    <monitor>Active</monitor>
    <primaryMonitor>Active</primaryMonitor>
  </placement>
  <theme>
    <name>Lubuntu-dark-panel</name>
    <titleLayout>SLIMC</titleLayout>
    <!--
      avaible characters are NDSLIMC, each can occur at most once.
      N: window icon
      L: window label (AKA title).
      I: iconify
      M: maximize
      C: close
      S: shade (roll up/down)
      D: omnipresent (on all desktops).
  -->
    <keepBorder>yes</keepBorder>
    <animateIconify>no</animateIconify>
    <font place="ActiveWindow">
      <name>Corbel</name>
      <size>8</size>
      <!-- font size in points -->
      <weight>Bold</weight>
      <!-- 'bold' or 'normal' -->
      <slant>Normal</slant>
      <!-- 'italic' or 'normal' -->
    </font>
    <font place="InactiveWindow">
      <name>Corbel</name>
      <size>7</size>
      <!-- font size in points -->
      <weight>Bold</weight>
      <!-- 'bold' or 'normal' -->
      <slant>Normal</slant>
      <!-- 'italic' or 'normal' -->
    </font>
    <font place="MenuHeader">
      <name>Corbel</name>
      <size>4</size>
      <!-- font size in points -->
      <weight>Bold</weight>
      <!-- 'bold' or 'normal' -->
      <slant>Normal</slant>
      <!-- 'italic' or 'normal' -->
    </font>
    <font place="MenuItem">
      <name>Corbel</name>
      <size>8</size>
      <!-- font size in points -->
      <weight>Normal</weight>
      <!-- 'bold' or 'normal' -->
      <slant>Normal</slant>
      <!-- 'italic' or 'normal' -->
    </font>
    <font place="ActiveOnScreenDisplay">
      <name/>
      <size>8</size>
      <weight/>
      <slant/>
    </font>
    <font place="InactiveOnScreenDisplay">
      <name>Sans</name>
      <size>8</size>
      <weight/>
      <slant/>
    </font>
  </theme>
  <desktops>
    <number>4</number>
    <firstdesk>1</firstdesk>
    <names>
      <name>filnavigation og browser</name>
      <name>sublime</name>
      <name>Windows o.lign.</name>
      <name>andet</name>
    </names>
    <popupTime>300</popupTime>
  </desktops>
  <resize>
    <drawContents>yes</drawContents>
    <popupShow>Never</popupShow>
    <!-- 'Always', 'Never', or 'Nonpixel' (xterms and such) -->
    <popupPosition>Center</popupPosition>
    <!-- 'Center' or 'Top' -->
    <popupFixedPosition>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
    </popupFixedPosition>
  </resize>
  <dock>
    <position>BottomRight</position>
    <!-- (Top|Bottom)(Left|Right|)|Top|Bottom|Left|Right|Floating -->
    <floatingX>0</floatingX>
    <floatingY>0</floatingY>
    <noStrut>no</noStrut>
    <stacking>Above</stacking>
    <!-- 'Above', 'Normal', or 'Below' -->
    <direction>Horizontal</direction>
    <!-- 'Vertical' or 'Horizontal' -->
    <autoHide>yes</autoHide>
    <hideDelay>5000</hideDelay>
    <!-- in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second) -->
    <showDelay>300</showDelay>
    <!-- in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second) -->
    <moveButton>Middle</moveButton>
    <!-- 'Left', 'Middle', 'Right' -->
  </dock>
  <keyboard>
    <chainQuitKey>C-g</chainQuitKey>
    <!-- Keybindings for sending windows to different desktops -->
    <keybind key="W-S-1">
      <action name="SendToDesktop">
        <desktop>1</desktop>
        <follow>no</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-S-2">
      <action name="SendToDesktop">
        <desktop>2</desktop>
        <follow>no</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-S-3">
      <action name="SendToDesktop">
        <desktop>3</desktop>
        <follow>no</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-S-4">
      <action name="SendToDesktop">
        <desktop>4</desktop>
        <follow>no</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-d">
      <action name="ToggleShowDesktop"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-d">
      <action name="ToggleDockAutohide"/>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings for windows -->
    <keybind key="A-Escape">
      <action name="Lower"/>
      <action name="FocusToBottom"/>
      <action name="Unfocus"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-space">
      <action name="ShowMenu">
        <menu>client-menu</menu>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings for desktop switching -->
    <keybind key="C-A-Left">
      <action name="DesktopLeft">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-Right">
      <action name="DesktopRight">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-Up">
      <action name="DesktopUp">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-Down">
      <action name="DesktopDown">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings for window switching -->
    <keybind key="A-Tab">
      <action name="NextWindow"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-S-Tab">
      <action name="PreviousWindow"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-Tab">
      <action name="NextWindow">
        <panels>yes</panels>
        <desktop>yes</desktop>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Tab">
      <action name="NextWindow">
        <allDesktops>yes</allDesktops>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-S-Tab">
      <action name="PreviousWindow">
        <allDesktops>yes</allDesktops>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- = Dock undecorated left -->
    <keybind key="W-Left">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>100%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!--  = Dock undecorated right -->
    <keybind key="W-Right">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>50%</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>100%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Dock undecorated up -->
    <keybind key="W-Up">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>100%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- = Dock undecorated down -->
    <keybind key="W-Down">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>50%</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>100%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- t = Dock undecorated Quadrant 1 -->
    <keybind key="W-Insert">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- = Dock undecorated Quadrant 2 -->
    <keybind key="W-Home">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>50%</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- e = Dock undecorated Quadrant 3 -->
    <keybind key="W-Delete">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>50%</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!--  Dock undecorated Quadrant 4 -->
    <keybind key="W-End">
      <action name="Unmaximize"/>
      <action name="Undecorate"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <x>50%</x>
        <y>50%</y>
        <height>50%</height>
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings for mpd/mpc -->
    <!--
    <keybind key="C-A-space">
      <action name="execute">
        <command>mpc toggle</command>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'play/pause'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-Next">
      <action name="execute">
        <execute>mpc next</execute>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'next'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-Prior">
      <action name="execute">
        <execute>mpc prev</execute>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'previous'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    -->
    <!-- Keybindings for volume control -->
    <!--
    <keybind key="C-Down">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -q set PCM 1- unmute</execute>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'volume down'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-Up">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -q set PCM 1+ unmute</execute>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'volume up'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-S-Up">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -q set Master 1+ unmute</execute>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'volume up'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-S-Down">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -q set Master 1- unmute</execute>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'volume down'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-End">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -q set PCM toggle</execute>
      </action>
      <action name="execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'mute'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    -->
    <!-- Keybindings for running applications -->
    <keybind key="Pause">
      <action name="ShowMenu">
        <menu>root-menu</menu>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-F1">
      <action name="ShowMenu">
        <menu>root-menu</menu>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-F2">
      <action name="execute">
        <execute>google-chrome-stable</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-F3">
      <action name="execute">
        <execute>sublime-text</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-F4">
      <action name="execute">
        <execute>krusader</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-F11">
      <action name="execute">
        <execute>killall soffice.bin</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-F7">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>spotify</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="C-A-Delete">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>xfce4-terminal -e htop</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="F1">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -D pulse -q sset Master toggle</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="F3">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -D pulse -q sset Master 5%- unmute</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="F4">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>amixer -D pulse -q sset Master 5%+ unmute</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F1">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>google-chrome-stable</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F2">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>killcalc</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F3">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>/home/urukrama/.scripts/only_terminal</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F4">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>/home/urukrama/.scripts/only_thunar</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F5">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>gmpc</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F6">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>epiphany</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F7">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>oowriter</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F8">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>/home/urukrama/.scripts/only_opera</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F9">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>stardict</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F10">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>gedit</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F11">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>gnome-alsamixer</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-F12">
      <action name="Execute">
        <execute>xlock -mousemotion +description -mode blank -bg black -fg grey30 -font '-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-110-*-*-*-*-*-*' -planfont '-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-110-*-*-*-*-*-*' -timeout 6 -info " " -username "  " -password " " -icongeometry 30x30</execute>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-a">
      <action name="ToggleMaximizeFull"/>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keychains to manage windows -->
    <keybind key="W-a">
      <keybind key="c">
        <action name="Close"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="m">
        <action name="ToggleMaximizeFull"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="n">
        <action name="ToggleOmnipresent"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="v">
        <action name="ToggleMaximizeVert"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="h">
        <action name="ToggleMaximizeHorz"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="s">
        <action name="ToggleShade"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="i">
        <action name="Iconify"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="t">
        <action name="ToggleAlwaysOnTop"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="S-b">
        <action name="ToggleAlwaysOnBottom"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="S-l">
        <action name="SendToNormalLayer"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="l">
        <action name="Lower"/>
        <action name="FocusToBottom"/>
        <action name="Unfocus"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="b">
        <action name="Lower"/>
        <action name="FocusToBottom"/>
        <action name="Unfocus"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="S-d">
        <action name="ToggleOmnipresent"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="d">
        <action name="ToggleDecorations"/>
      </keybind>
      <!--       <keybind key="n">
        <action name="SendToDesktopNext">
          <wrap>no</wrap>
          <follow>no</follow>
        </action>
      </keybind> -->
      <keybind key="p">
        <action name="SendToDesktopPrevious">
          <wrap>no</wrap>
          <follow>no</follow>
        </action>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="g">
        <keybind key="Left">
          <action name="GrowToEdgeWest"/>
        </keybind>
        <keybind key="Right">
          <action name="GrowToEdgeEast"/>
        </keybind>
        <keybind key="Down">
          <action name="GrowToEdgeSouth"/>
        </keybind>
        <keybind key="Up">
          <action name="GrowToEdgeNorth"/>
        </keybind>
      </keybind>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings for managing Openbox -->
    <keybind key="C-A-R-T">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>osdctl -s 'reconfiguring'</command>
      </action>
      <action name="Reconfigure"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-o">
      <keybind key="e">
        <action name="Execute">
          <execute>/home/urukrama/.scripts/logout</execute>
        </action>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="s">
        <action name="Execute">
          <execute>/home/urukrama/.scripts/shutdown</execute>
        </action>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="r">
        <action name="Execute">
          <command>osdctl -s 'reconfiguring'</command>
        </action>
        <action name="Reconfigure"/>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="c">
        <action name="Execute">
          <execute>mousepad /home/urukrama/.config/openbox/rc.xml</execute>
        </action>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="m">
        <action name="Execute">
          <execute>mousepad /home/urukrama/.config/openbox/menu.xml</execute>
        </action>
      </keybind>
      <keybind key="l">
        <action name="Execute">
          <execute>xlock -mousemotion +description -mode blank -bg black -fg grey30 -font '-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-110-*-*-*-*-*-*' -planfont '-adobe-helvetica-bold-r-normal--*-110-*-*-*-*-*-*' -timeout 6 -info " " -username "  " -password " " -icongeometry 30x30</execute>
        </action>
      </keybind>
    </keybind>
    <!-- EMILS SHORTCUTSxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-->
    <keybind key="S-W-Right">
      <action name="SendToDesktopRight">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
        <follow>yes</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="S-W-Left">
      <action name="SendToDesktopLeft">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
        <follow>yes</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="S-W-Up">
      <action name="SendToDesktopUp">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
        <follow>yes</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="S-W-Down">
      <action name="SendToDesktopDown">
        <wrap>no</wrap>
        <follow>yes</follow>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Window Tiling: Emulates Windows 7 Snap feature -->
    <!-- <keybind key="W-Left">
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
      <action name="MoveToEdgeWest"/>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Right">
      <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
      <action name="MaximizeVert"/>
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <width>50%</width>
      </action>
      <action name="MoveToEdgeEast"/>
    </keybind> -->
    <!-- aktiver dmenu -->
    <keybind key="C-space">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>dmenu_run -b -i -l 20 -fn '10x20'</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings to move windows -->
    <!--  <keybind key="W-Right">
      <action name="MoveRelative">
        <x>30</x>
        <y>0</y>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Left">
      <action name="MoveRelative">
        <x>-30</x>
        <y>0</y>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Down">
      <action name="MoveRelative">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>30</y>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-Up">
      <action name="MoveRelative">
        <x>0</x>
        <y>-30</y>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="W-c">
      <action name="MoveToCenter"/>
    </keybind>    -->
    <!--close -->
    <keybind key="A-C-f">
      <action name="Close"/>
    </keybind>
    <!-- move the window to the first monitor -->
    <keybind key="W-Prior">
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <monitor>1</monitor>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- move the window to the second monitor -->
    <keybind key="W-Next">
      <action name="MoveResizeTo">
        <monitor>2</monitor>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Launch a terminal on Ctrl + Alt + T-->
    <keybind key="C-A-T">
      <action name="Execute">
        <command>lxsession-default terminal</command>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings to toggle fullscreen -->
    <keybind key="F11">
      <action name="ToggleFullscreen"/>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Keybindings to resize windows -->
    <keybind key="A-W-S-Up">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <bottom>-12.5</bottom>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-W-S-Down">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <top>-12.5</top>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-W-S-Right">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <left>-12.5</left>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-W-S-Left">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <right>-12.5</right>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-W-Down">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <bottom>12.5</bottom>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-W-Up">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <top>12.5</top>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-W-Left">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <left>12.5</left>
      </action>
    </keybind>
    <keybind key="A-W-Right">
      <action name="ResizeRelative">
        <right>12.5</right>
      </action>
    </keybind>
  </keyboard>
  <mouse>
    <dragThreshold>3</dragThreshold>
    <!-- number of pixels the mouse must move before a drag begins -->
    <doubleClickTime>200</doubleClickTime>
    <!-- in milliseconds (1000 = 1 second) -->
    <context name="Frame">
      <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Press">
        <action name="Focus"/>
        <action name="Raise"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Click">
        <action name="Unshade"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Drag">
        <action name="Move"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-Right" action="Press">
        <action name="Focus"/>
        <action name="Raise"/>
        <action name="Unshade"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-Right" action="Drag">
        <action name="Resize"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-Middle" action="Press">
        <action name="Lower"/>
        <action name="FocusToBottom"/>
        <action name="Unfocus"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-Up" action="Click">
        <action name="DesktopPrevious"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-Down" action="Click">
        <action name="DesktopNext"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="C-A-Up" action="Click">
        <action name="DesktopPrevious"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="C-A-Down" action="Click">
        <action name="DesktopNext"/>
      </mousebind>
      <mousebind button="A-S-Up" action="Click">
        <action name="SendToDesktopPrevious"/>
      </mousebind>
```

### END here cause of character limit on stackexchange

Comment: Can you edit your question to include  ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc. Also if you changed it did you remember to run openbox --reconfigure to load the new file otherwise the old file will still be in memory.

Comment: included :) - I did run openbox --reconfigure, and I can tell it read it into memory because some of keyboard shortcuts works as they have done the last two years. The common denominator for the non-working ones seems to be that they resize windows, or change windows from one desktop to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the Software Updater ran yesterday, all my shortcuts are working again. Very strange, but very relieving.